# String searching algorithm for Chinese characters

Tags: python, unicode, cjk, string-search

There is Python code available for normal string searching algorithms, such as Boyer-Moore. I am looking to use this on Chinese characters, but it doesn't seem like the same implementation would work. What would I do in order to make the algorithm work with Chinese characters? I am referring to this:

http://en.literateprograms.org/Boyer-Moore_string_search_algorithm_(Python)#References

Answer (score 3):

As long as all your text is in unicodes it should work just fine. The algorithm looks sequence-independent, provided each "element" is one sequence-unit in length.